# Try Catch WebDriverTimeoutException does not work

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 catches within my try catch block, however the WebDriverTimeoutException does not get caught at all. The other exception is being caught correctly. The test fails on the timeout exception "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException :Timed out after 20 seconds"

So why is that the WebDriverTimeoutException try catch is not being caught at all?

```
    public IWebElement FindElement(By howBy)
    {

        TimeSpan _elementTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);


        IWebElement elementfound = null;

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, _elementTimeOut);
        wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
        {
            try
            {
                elementfound = WebDriver.FindElement(howBy);
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException f)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please fail WebDriverTimeoutException");
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please fail NoSuchElementException");
            }

            return elementfound;
        });

        return elementfound;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the `WebDriverTimeoutException` isn't caught within your anonymous method inside the `Until()` block is that the timeout exception isn't **thrown** by your anonymous method. You'll need to catch the timeout **outside** the `Until()` method. To wit:

```
public IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver, By howBy)
{
    TimeSpan elementTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    IWebElement elementfound = null;

    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, elementTimeOut);
        elementFound = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
        {
            try
            {
                elementfound = driver.FindElement(howBy);
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please fail NoSuchElementException");
            }

            return elementfound;
        });
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please fail WebDriverTimeoutException");
    }

    return elementfound;
}
```

Note further that `WebDriverWait` already catches the `NoSuchElementException` as part of its normal operation, so you're reinventing the wheel a little with your example. A more compact and efficient method doing the same thing would look like the following:

```
public IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver, By howBy)
{
    TimeSpan elementTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    IWebElement elementfound = null;

    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, elementTimeOut);
        elementFound = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => driver.FindElement(howBy));
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please fail WebDriverTimeoutException");
    } 

    return elementfound;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much JimEvans, your suggestion really worked. Now my method looks smaller and it's more efficient.