# Unable to catch WebDriverTimeoutException in user code

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException. I want to catch this exception in code, but I can't do it. Program ignores try/catch.

```
Exception „OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException” in WebDriver.dll
```

I have read [Try Catch WebDriverTimeoutException does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309611/try-catch-webdrivertimeoutexception-does-not-work) and tried to use it's solution, but program ignores catch.

```
private IWebElement GetElement(IWebDriver driver, By howBy)
    {
        TimeSpan elementTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
        IWebElement elementfound = null;

        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, elementTimeOut);
            elementfound = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => driver.FindElement(howBy));
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please fail WebDriverTimeoutException");
            driver.Quit();
        }


        return elementfound;
    }
```

I am using this method here:

```
            IWebElement searchResult = GetElement(drivers.driver, By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'example')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of seeing if an element is present.

```
   bool link = IsElementPresent_byXpath("//td[contains(text(),'example')]");

    public static bool IsElementPresent_byXpath(string xpath)
    {
        bool result;
        try { result = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Displayed; }
        catch (NoSuchElementException) { return false; }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { return false; }
        return result;
    }
```

Then you can do something like:

```
            if (link)
        {
            //do something with it
        }
```

Then something like this with a timeout exception:

```
WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath("//td[contains(text(),'example')]");

    public static bool WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(string path)
    {
        var result = true;
        try { _wait.Until(driver=> driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path)).Displayed); }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(path); }
        catch (NoSuchElementException) { WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(path); }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { result = false; }
        return result;
    }
```